# how to fade parent $mdDialog?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I use parent $mdDialog and child $mdDialog inside parent controller.

main controller

```
 $scope.openItemEdit = function (item, ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'app/item-config.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            controller: 'ParentController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            fullscreen: vm.isCustomFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            locals: {item: item}
        })
            .then(function () {
                $scope.status = 'ok';
            }, function () {
                $scope.status = 'cancel';
            });
    };
```

inside parent controller:

```
function addMembers( ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'app/add-members.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            controller: 'ChildController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            preserveScope: true,
            fullscreen: vm.isCustomFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            autoWrap: true,
            skipHide: true
        })
    }
```

I want to fade parent dialog window when I open it's child. is there way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following. the idea is to open the child dialog when the user clicks on ok on the parent dialog.
and don't do anything on cancel.

```
$scope.openItemEdit = function (item, ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'app/item-config.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            controller: 'ParentController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            fullscreen: vm.isCustomFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            locals: {item: item}
        })
            .then(function () {
                $scope.status = 'ok';

                    $mdDialog.show({
                                templateUrl: 'app/add-members.html',
                                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                                controller: 'ChildController',
                                controllerAs: 'vm',
                                targetEvent: ev,
                                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                                preserveScope: true,
                                fullscreen: vm.isCustomFullscreen, 
                                autoWrap: true,
                                skipHide: true
                            })
            }, function () {
                $scope.status = 'cancel';
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

in child  $mdDialog. there is property called:  'parent'-here we deside to what DOM we attach dialog window. So I changed it a bit and now parent dialog window fades.

```
function addMembers( ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'appadd-members.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.getElementById('ParentDialog')),
            controller: 'AddMembersController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            preserveScope: true,
            fullscreen: vm.isCustomFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            autoWrap: true,
            skipHide: true
        })
    }
```